# Trying to retrieve song title from Shoutcast using multiple methods, none of which are working. Please see

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, fsockopen, shoutcast

I have been searching high and low all over the internet for scripts and methods that can fetch song info from shoutcast streams using php. While all of them work great on localhost, they all fail when uploaded on webhost (which is 000webhost.com by the way).

These are the methods that I used :

1. using fsockopen... In this case it gives the "Connection timed out" error.
   On searching over the internet I learned that the webhost might be blocking outbound   connections.
2. Then I moved on to the file_get_contents method. Here, the return value is coming to be false. I already checked that allow_url_fopen is on through phpinfo()
3. Then I moved on to using curl through the following code:

   `$curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://s8.voscast.com:8562/");
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2) Gecko/20070219 Firefox/2.0.0.2');
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
   $shoutcast=curl_exec($curl);`

Again, this returns false. Please note that I have commented out the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION because that statement gives the error that it can't be used when php is running in safe mode.

Is there no other way? Whatever scripts/methods/tutorials/suggestions I've found out use one of these three methods when they are not working for me at all.

Please note that they run JUST FINE on my computer, i.e, on localhost. But as soon as they are uploaded on the webhost, it stops working.

Is there any other way/workaround/method that we can try? I just need to get the title of the song playing and nothing else.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To determine the metadata, you must make a connection to the SHOUTcast server in some way.  Unfortunately, 000webhost.com is a pretty terrible hosting provider, providing a level of service that is insufficient for your needs.  They limit what connections you can make, which is likely the issue you're running into.

The only way around this is to use a hosting provider that allows you to make connections to other servers.  Note that even providers that allow you to make connections sometimes do not allow connections outside of port 80.  If you want to be sure that you can do what you want, consider a $5 VPS instance, from Digital Ocean or similar.

As an alternative to all this, I have a free [service that can send your SHOUTcast metadata to your clients via AJAX](http://audiopump.co/accounts/).  Then, you can use any host you want.